# React: How to implement a function that collects table row data and pass that data to a state in another component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-component, react-state

In my react app, I have a button which when clicked I want that table row data to be collected and passed to a state in another component.

Basically i have two components. `Table` and the 2nd is `Table Edit modal`. I only want to manage one state and that is the state found in my `Table Edit modal`. I have an edit button on each row found in `Table` which i want it to pass that row data for it to be stored in the state found in `Table Edit modal``.

My code is not working. I'm getting an error that points to the **Table** component

> 'editEmployeeData' is not defined  no-undef

**Table** component

```
const EmployeeTable = (props) => {
  const employeesDetail = useSelector((state) => state.hr_data.employeesDetail);
  const modalState = useSelector((state) => state.hr_data.modalState);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getEmployeeData());
  }, [dispatch]);

  const classes = useStyles();

  const columns = [
      { name: "name", label: "Name" },
      { name: "phone_no", label: "Contact" },
      { name: "email", label: "Email" },
      { name: "department", label: "Department" },
      { name: "salary", label: "Salary" },
      { name: "date_employed", label: "Date Employed" },
      {
        name: "Actions",
        options: {
          filter: true,
          sort: false,
          empty: true,
          customBodyRender: (value, tableMeta, updateValue) => {
            const i = tableMeta.rowIndex;
            const data = this.employeesDetail;
            return (
              // OPEN MODAL
              <Fragment>
                <Tooltip title="Edit">
                  <EditIcon                        <==== EDIT BUTTON
                    color="action"
                    onClick={()=> editEmployeeData(   <==== EVENT THAT COLLECTS THE FIELDS DATA
                      data[i].id,
                      data[i].name,
                      data[i].phone_no,
                      data[i].email,
                      data[i].department,
                      data[i].job_title,
                      data[i].salary,
                      data[i].date_employed
                    )}
                  />
                </Tooltip>
              </Fragment>
            );
          },
        },
      },
  ];

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>

      {/* EDIT EMPLOYEE MODAL */}
      <EditEmployeeModal
        toggleModal={() => dispatch(toggleModal())} // modal activate
        updateEmployeeData={() => dispatch(updateEmployeeData())}
        modalState={modalState} // boolean
        editEmployeeData={editEmployeeData}      <==== PASSING HERE
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default EmployeeTable;
```

**Edit Table data** component/modal

```
class EditEmployeeModal extends Component {
  state = {
    id: "",
    name: "",
    phone_no: "",
    email: "",
    department: "",
    job_title: "",
    salary: "",
    date_employed: "",
  }

  editEmployeeData(       <==== NOT WORKING
    id,
    name,
    phone_no,
    email,
    department,
    job_title,
    salary,
    date_employed
  ) {
    this.setState({
      id,
      name,
      phone_no,
      email,
      department,
      job_title,
      salary,
      date_employed,
    });
    this.props.toggleModal();
  }
...
export default EditEmployeeModal;
```